# Why is FindBugs showing warning for redundant null check

Tags: java, findbugs

```
if (first != null && second != null && !first.equals(second)) {
  // not null & not equal
} else if (first == null ^ second == null) {
  // not both null and not both not null
  // (first == null && second != null) || (first != null && second == null)
} else {
  // both null or equal
}
```

FindBugs is complaining about else if (first == null ^ second == null) {...}

Comment: What `^` supposed to do?

Comment: @Smit Bitwise XOR (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: IMO you may rewrite your conditions in a simpler way =\

Comment: when you say complaining, could you give the full error/warning message?

Comment: @Meesh Thanks but my point was why `^` in `if`. If OP want to check then `else if (first == null || second == null) {` would be much cleaner.

Comment: What FindBugs check exactly is giving you the warning? There are several with "redundant null check" in their names.

Comment: @Smit it is not equivalent...

Comment: I think `!=` would be clearer than `XOR`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it is only software.

Comment: No, FindBugs isn't like that, Martijn.

Comment: @centoclaus it's a redundant null check cause you're doing XOR between two booleans...

Comment: @alfasin can you elaborate?

Comment: @centoclaus As I explained in the comments above, even though the code is correct (and working) the fact that you XOR booleans makes FindBugs suspect that you don't know what you're doing and thus the warning. Again, it doesn't mean that the code is not correct - only that it is suspected as a potential bug and should be double-checked.

Comment: @Thomas Yes it is like that, it is only software, and far from perfect. Last time I used it I had to write an astonishing number of exception rules, to add to an already astonishing number of exception rules that the project already had before I arrived.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote in the comment: `not both null` it's a good thing that FindBugs showed you your (potential) mistake since you should have used `&&` (AND) not `^` (XOR):

```
first != null && second != null
```

or alternatively:

```
!(first == null || second == null)
```

**UPDATE:**
The OP change the comment to: "not both null and not both not null" this condition requires a different `if`:

```
(first == null && second != null) || (first != null && second == null)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
first == null ^ second == null
```

only that the former version is more readable.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux :)))

Comment: I meant first and second not both null and first and second not both not null. Basically, I want ((first != null && second == null) || (first == null && second != null))

Comment: @centoclaus so you'll have to check separately - unless you're sure that the only wrong case is where first == second and then you can use XOR

Comment: @alfasin: How does that explain the warning of FindBugs? `(first == null && second != null) || (first != null && second == null)` is IMO identical to `first == null ^ second == null`?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I didn't say that these conditions are not equivalent (my first answer was to the original comment!). In fact they are! FindBugs issues a warning cause it is a **potential** bug (in case the programmer doesn't understand what's he doing)

Comment: That is not what "redundant" means I think?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux again - this is **potentially** a bug since he's checking nullity but "doesn't do anything with it" because of the XOR which means that the result "was lost". It's not the case, true, but it is a good warning cause it could have been done by mistake, in fact, this is a very good warning! pay attention that it doesn't generate a compilation warning and that's exactly why FindBugs issues an alert!

Comment: In this case, it is better. The "readable" form creates four branches, since && and || are short circuit. While ^ is a single operation and doesn't create any extra branches. You say *"doesn't do anything with it"*, but he actually does: he uses it in an if condition. Using a XOR in this situation doesn't make the checks redundant in any way. And I don't see how writing this could be done my mistake.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux you don't have to explain to me what the code does - I added quotes around that sentence to emphasis that FidnBugs suspects that it's not doing what it actually does. IMHO you should be able to read code like you read a book. Most of the people that will run into code that's written this way will have to stop and think if it really does what it's meant to do. This is bad. very bad. Especially in an era where we have (multi-core) CPUs that can do millions of commands per second - it's meaningless if we'll preform 3 or 6 commands!

Comment: @alfasin We have had millions of instruction per second for over 30 years actually. I fail to see how it relates to code readability. I would expect any competent programmer to understand the OP's code, and I expect FindBugs to do likewise.

Comment: @EJP 1. "I fail to see how it relates to code readability" - I also wrote (if you bother to read the entire sentence): "it's meaningless if we'll preform 3 or 6 commands!" - which means that efficiency should not be factored - it was as a response to Martijn's last comment about performance. 2. "I would expect any competent programmer to understand the OP's code" - did I write that programmers will fail to understand the code ? please read again!

Comment: @EJP by the way, about 30 years ago we had less than 1 MIPS (million instructions per second) : http://books.google.com/books?id=uXyCqEJYITAC&lpg=PA41&ots=tQgh4pMlz-&dq=cpu%20instructions%20per%20%20second%20evolution&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q=cpu%20instructions%20per%20%20second%20evolution&f=false and second,

Comment: @alfasin, I disagree.  You should expect competence, but guard against incompetence by writing easy to understand code.  Logical if branches relying on bit manipulation are not often encountered, and will trip up the unwary.

Comment: @GGB667 actually it sounds like we DO agree :)

Answer (score 0):

The ^ operator is a bitwise operator as opposed to a logical operator.  While technically correct the precedence of the operators makes the expression confusing should the logical expressions grow.  I don't use FindBugs but I would call the 3rd line suspect - Wrap it in parentheses or rewrite it.

```
 ...
 } else if ((first == null) ^ (second == null)) {
 ...
```

^ can behave like a logical operation as long as the operands are boolean values. Because the precedence is different for each logical and bitwise operator, you should always group with parentheses since the order of evaluation will not be left to right but will be based on the table here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Your expression "not both null" and "not both not null" comes out like this:

`(first == null) || second == null) && !((first == null && second == null))`

Which is pretty confusing but it is what you are asking for.

I am not sure what you are doing in the blocks but it might be easier to write the entire block like this:

```
if(first!=null && !first.equals(second)) {
  // first is not null and the first and second are not equal
} else if (second!=null && !second.equals(first)) {
  // second is not null and first and second are not equal
} else {
  // all that is left is that first and second are both null OR neither one is null but they are equal
}
```

Comment: The ^ (XOR) operator is both a bitwise operator and a Boolean operator, depending on its arguments. The remainder of your answer agrees with that, and contradicts your opening sentence. Make up your mind. -1

Comment: I will make an edit to make it clearer. ^ is strictly a bitwise operator but when performed on two boolean values it behaves like a logical operator because that is the outcome of bit comparison on boolean values.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Answer (score 0):

The warning says: **redundant null check**. Thus, FindBugs thinks that you are redundantly checking the nullity of the variables. Try if this code also triggers the warning:

```
    Boolean firstNull = (first == null);
    Boolean secondNull = (second == null);
    Boolean equalFirstSecond = first.equals(second);

    if (!firstNull && !secondNull && !equalFirstSecond) {
        // not null & not equal
    } else if (firstNull ^ secondNull){
        // not both null and not both not null
    } else {
        // both null or equal
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

> if (first != null && second != null && !first.equals(second)) {

You don't need to test `second != null` here. The `equals()` call does that.

> } else if (first == null ^ second == null) {

You should return `false` in this case, assuming this is an `equals()` method itself.

If FindBugs doesn't like it with this change I would ignore it, it doesn't know what it's talking about. It's not perfect. Put in an exception rule.